# strncpy doesn't trim properly - same length

Tags: c++

I have made a program that should trim a string from both ends, like in this example:

---

For 12345 I should have: `1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345; 2, 23, 234, 2345; 3, 34, 345; 4, 45; 5`

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
char text[30]="123456", text2[30], text3[30];
int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(text); i++)
    {
        strcpy(text2, text+i);
        for(int j=1; j<=strlen(text)-i; j++)
        {
            strncpy(text3, text2, j);
            cout<<text3<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The part with eliminating the first character works, but when I use strncpy to eliminate from the end of the string I get results having the same length as the string I wanted to be trimmed; for example I get 55555 instead of only 5. I tried to initialise `text3` with `text3[0]='\0'` before `strncpy` in it, but I keep getting the same results and I have no idea why. I did put `cout<<j` before strncpy to see how many characters it copies and the numbers matched perfectly the length of the remaining string.

Comment: `strncpy()` doesn't null-terminate the target string unless it has exhausted the input sting and there is still room in the target for a trailing null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the output when we initialize `text` with `"1234"`:

```
1
12
123
1234
2234
2334
2344
3344
3444
4444
```

`strncpy` is copying into the text3 buffer, but the content that was already there remains, because it doesn't null-terminate. If you ignore the remaining characters, you can see the desired output is copied over the beginning.

1
12
123
1234
2<s>234</s>
23<s>34</s>
234<s>4</s>
3<s>344</s>
34<s>44</s>
4<s>444</s>

So, you need to null-terminate the copied portion. After `strncpy`, you could do `text3[j] = 0;`.

[Observe this in action](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5e0cce6c78de5fd8)

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  string str = "12345";
  int b, e;
  for(int b = 0; b < str.length(); b++)
    for(int e = b + 1; e < str.length() - b; e++)
      cout << str.substr(b, e) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```